# Why does the Phantom repeatedly mention Carlotta's throat in "The Phantom of the Opera"?

Tags: french-language, gaston-leroux, the-phantom-of-the-opera

When Erik is monologuing to Christine in his room underneath the Opera, and Raoul and the Persian are trapped in the torture chamber, Erik says this:

> Meantime, the other had already begun to play the ventriloquist. He said:
> "Here, I raise my mask a little... Oh, only a little!... You see my lips, such lips as I have? They're not moving! [...]  What does it say? '*I am the little bag of life and death!*'... And now, crack! It is in Carlotta's throat, in Carlotta's golden throat, in Carlotta's crystal throat, as I live! What does it say? It says, 'It's I, Mr. Toad, it's I singing! *I feel without alarm—co-ack—with its melody enwind me—co-ack!'... And now, crack! It is on a chair in the ghost's box and it says, '*Madame Carlotta is singing to-night to bring the chandelier down!*'... And now, crack! Aha! Where is Erik's voice now? Listen, Christine, darling! Listen!["]
> <sub>*The Phantom of the Opera*, chapter XXIII: "The Tortures Begin" (translation by Alexander Teixeira de Mattos, 1911)</sub>

Why does Erik mention Carlotta's throat so many times?

> It is in Carlotta's throat, in Carlotta's golden throat, in Carlotta's crystal throat, as I live!

This is three repetitions of a similar phrase, with a different descriptor each time. The Phantom repeats himself several times in this monologue, but this one jumped out at me as being excessive - it's repeated three times. Why does Erik mention Carlotta's throat so many times in this monologue?

Comment: Not familiar with the story (I don't think watching Phantom of the Paradise counts) but I'd guess it's because the throat is important for singing, but is also a vulnerable place where you can kill someone.

Comment: Isn't he explaining how he managed to make Carlotta croak like a toad earlier in the novel?  Or is that not what you're asking?